# How to capture a IList embeded into model in the Controller class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view-model which has the name HomeViewModel. I also have another viewmodel TaskViewModel. I have included the TaskViewModel into the HomeViewModel as a IList

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public IList<TaskViewModel> myTaskList {get; set;}
}
```

In the view I use below code to capture data from the user:

```
@model My.ViewModels.HomeViewModel

                                    <div>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.myTaskList[0].Description)
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.myTaskList[0].Hours)

                                        <button onclick="showTheRepeatedFields() ">Add Task</button>
                                    </div>
```

IN the controller I receive all the other parameters for the "HomeViewModel " but not the IList.
The controller is as below;

```
public JsonResult SaveWork(int Supervisor, DateTime In, DateTime Out, int Employee, string Description, IList<TaskViewModel> myTaskList)
```

When I hit debug I get null for myTaskList in the method signature. What can be the issue

Comment: Can you please try this `public List<TaskViewModel> myTaskList {get; set;}` in your action parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You should try putting your list generation inside a `for` loop:

```
<div>
    @for (var i = 0; i < model.myTaskList.Count; i++) 
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.myTaskList[i].Description)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.myTaskList[i].Hours)
    }
    <button onclick="showTheRepeatedFields() ">Add Task</button>
</div>
```

I know that it makes no sense if you already knows that your `myTaskList` collection will have always one element, but with the for loop ASP.Net is able to generate the form's elements in a way that allows it to manage the model binding to be able to populate the variables in the controller's method.

Comment: Also, you could try changing your controller's method signature to:
`public JsonResult SaveWork(HomeViewModel homeViewModel)` 
Maybe that could be a better approach, since if you need to add a new variable to `HomeViewModel`, you don't need to add it in the method signature also